# How to load Data given in textboxes of html page in the below table of html page?

Tags: html

[data given in surname,postcode,textboxes must be loaded in below table when create customer link is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIQbu.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my code as your requirement:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="choice_type">
        <option>select</option>
        <option value="part_type">part_type</option>
        <option value="category">category</option>
        <option value="names">names</option>
        </select>    
    </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <th>VAL</th>
    <th>VAL DESC</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="text" name="val"  id="val" size="15" /></td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="val_desc"  id="val_desc" size="15" /></td>
</tr>
```

The getData() function is as follows:

```
function getData(){ 
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
var id=document.getElementById("choice_type").value;
var url="choice_retrieval.jsp";//The code for this file is defined below 
url=url+"?choice_type="+id;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(){ 
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
var strar = showdata.split(":");
if(strar.length>1){
var strname = strar[1];
document.getElementById("val").value= strar[1];
document.getElementById("val_desc").value= strar[2];
}
}
```

The Code snippet for choice_retrieval.jsp is as follows:

```
<%
String ch = request.getParameter("choice_type").toString();
System.out.println(ch);
String data ="";
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://", "", "");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from master_panel where 
   choice_type='"+ch+"'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        data = ":" + rs.getString("val") + ": " + rs.getString("val_desc");
    }
    out.println(data);
    System.out.println(data);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

i think it can help you , All The Best..